# Remove all elements from an ArrayList that contains string

Tags: c#, arraylist

I've been trying to figure out how to remove elements in my ArrayList where the value contains some text string.

My Array could look like this:

```
[0] "\"MAERSKA.CO\",N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A"
[1] "\"GEN.COABB.ST\",N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A"
[2] "\"ARCM.ST\",\"Arcam AB\",330.00,330.50,332.00,330.50,330.00"
```

And my ArrayList is created like this:

```
string stringToRemove = "NA";   
ArrayList rows = new ArrayList(csvData.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n'));
```

So the question is how I delete all entries that contains "NA".
I have tried the RemoveAt or RemoveAll with several combinations of Contains but i cant seem to get the code right.

I do not want to make a new Array if it can be avoided.

Regards
Flemming

Comment: Please write what was and what become.

Comment: what about  string.Replace(data, "")  ?
rows = new ArrayList(csvData.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n').Select(st => st.Replace(st, "")));

Comment: The solution from Simser & Gabba both works equaly perfect.
Accept goes to Simser as 2 solutions were provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce your ArrayList before instantiate your variable, consider using LINQ:

```
ArrayList rows = new ArrayList(csvData.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n').Where(r => !r.Contains(stringToRemove)).ToList());
```

If you want to reduce your ArrayList after instantiation, you can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = (string)rows[i];
    if (row.Contains(stringToRemove))
    {
        rows.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a list as output containing all strings except "N/A":

```
var outputs = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in input)
{
    var splitted = item.Split(',');
    foreach (var splt in splitted)
    {
        if (splt != "N/A")
        {
            outputs.Add(splt);
        }
    }
}
```

The input is your array.

Comment: I think the question was to remove entries/rows containing "N/A", not creating a new list of all words except "N/A".

Comment: Thanks for contribution.
I can use this solution elsewere but answers below fits solution to question better.